# HP Elitebook X360 830 G6 laptop - WIN 11 23H2 - lost program for Calendar Appointments in To-do Pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, to-do, appointments

Back in the day working with MS Office 2013, I came across a program to add MS Outlook calendar appointments, event, to the right hand To-do pane.

Since migrating my information from old laptop to the new the software has vanished; whether it was me or the techo we cannot agree on.  I can remember it was a ZIP or RAR file and named something like Officeoutlookaddin.msi.

Can anyone help as it is an important piece od software.  I believe MS has state it is no longer supported.

Comment: Office 2013 is now out of support.  Consider upgrading to Office 365.  Calendar and To Do are very much supported in Office 365.  That said, Office 365 might not work like Office 2013.

Comment: Thanks, John however I'm up-to-date with Office.  I'm using Dock a Peek but that only shows 7 days.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

If you remember the name of the add-in, you can reinstall it. It's also possible that it's not supported now, as mentioned in the thread below:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-calendar-peek-max-days-is-only-7/ce65127b-0d6c-41f0-a5c7-f4ea4099a36a

As you know, we can now use Outlook Calendar Peek instead,
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keep-upcoming-appointments-and-meetings-always-in-view-0e5f30da-c44d-4b96-8fd9-ba5d10db0962